Snowflake - Task graph
Task1 has more than one root task a, b. Both the root tasks are suspended and they don't have predecessors. How to enable the root tasks? Can you please give the command?

Hi - do you just need to resume the two parent tasks, one by one,  or is there something more complicated in your question that I'm missing?

To enable the root task you can run resume the task and later manually trigger it to run it via execute task  ;
ALTER TASK [ IF EXISTS ]  RESUME | SUSPEND;
EXECUTE TASK ;

One option is to create a root task for the graph, creating a common predecessor for all parent tasks. It would look something like this:
          => task a
root_task           => task 1
          => task b

The root task runs first, followed by both Task A and Task B, and then when they are finished, Task 1 runs. In this scenario, the only task you ever have to suspend or resume is the root task, which would suspend or resume essentially the entire task graph.
